# How can I make this label to just show different string values at each case

Tags: vb.net

Take a look at the simple code below. It is suppose to show string values at different case but the output is only the first one: "what is your email". Please, I need explanation.

The objective is to change the labll text upon click event on next button on the form.

```
Public Class Form4PassworRecovery
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1Next.Click
        Label1Intro.Hide()

        Select Case counter
            Case 0
                Question("What is your Email?")
            Case 1
                Question("What is your favorite Hobby")
            Case 2
                Question("What is your minor")
        End Select
        counter += 1
        Answer()
    End Sub

    Sub Answer()
        Dim A As New TextBox
        A.Location = New Point(66.5, 120)
        A.ForeColor = Color.White
        A.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(153, 217, 255)
        A.Size = New Point(400, 29)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(A)
        A.Show()
    End Sub

    Sub Question(ByVal Question As String)
        Dim Q As New Label
        Q.Text = Question
        Q.Location = New Point(66.5, 90)
        Q.Size = New Point(400, 29)
        Q.ForeColor = Color.White
        Q.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(153, 217, 255)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Q)
        Q.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Button1.Text = "Cancel" Then
            Me.Hide()
            Me.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Am expecting the output of the form to be different string value at each case but I kept receiving only the first string value.

Comment: Are you placing all the labels on top of each other in the same position?

Comment: Also, `Q.Size = New Point(400, 29)`? this should be `New Size(400, 29)`. `Q.Location = New Point(66.5, 90)` this is a `PointF`. Is your code compiling?

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Indeed I think I was putting the same labels on top of each other. I just declared the labels and the textbox outside the functions. It worked by updating the values at each call. New point is compiling fine but again thanks for the insight. perhaps new size is better one.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: Your code will not compile with Option Strint On. The Point constructor takes (Int32, Int32) 66.5 is not an Int32. if you require that precision, you are not getting it. You would know that if you had Option Strict On.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the locations on your form and then increment them as you place each Label and TextBox pairing:

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim labelLocation As Point = New Point(5, 5)
    Dim textBoxLocation As Point = New Point(5, 30)

    Private Sub Button1Next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1Next.Click
        Label1Intro.Hide()

        Select Case counter
            Case 0
                Question("What is your Email?")
            Case 1
                Question("What is your favorite Hobby")
            Case 2
                Question("What is your minor")
        End Select
        counter += 1
        Answer()
    End Sub

    Sub Question(ByVal Question As String)

        Dim Q As New Label
        Q.Text = Question
        Q.Location = labelLocation

        Q.Size = New Size(400, 29)
        Q.ForeColor = Color.White
        Q.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(153, 217, 255)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Q)
        Q.Show()

        textBoxLocation = New Point(labelLocation.X, labelLocation.Y + Q.Height + 7)
        labelLocation = New Point(labelLocation.X, textBoxLocation.Y + 7 + Q.Height)

    End Sub

    Sub Answer()

        Dim A As New TextBox
        A.Location = textBoxLocation

        A.ForeColor = Color.White
        A.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(153, 217, 255)
        A.Size = New Size(400, 29)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(A)
        A.Show()

    End Sub
```